# Meaning of Scrapper 142's words to Thor

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

At some point in *Thor: Ragnarok*, our favorite Valkyrie tells Thor:

> Don't die. You know what I mean.

Maybe I'm missing something, but why the second part? It seems to be a self-explaining sentence. Despite rumors that the Asgardian gods can't die,

- > Odin died (old age)
- > Hela was surprised to see Thor and Loki alive
- > Hela dies at the end

So, what is Scrapper 142's meaning?

Comment: My own interpretation was something like : 'I want to have 'fun' with you when this will be over'. (The kind of fun that don't need clothes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this means that she once again accepted Asgard as her home, is willing to fight for it and accepts Thor as her king (note that she also starts this line with "Your Majesty"), as opposed to how previously she was not interested in going back or helping Thor at all.

The "You know what I mean" is probably because she's still a tough woman and did't want to get sentimental. The "Your Majesty" already used up her sentiment quota for the day.